# Join words with double quotes

Tags: python-3.x

Here is the list:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

i want to convert list to string like this:

```
string = '"a", "b", "c"'
```

I've tried with join, but couldn't. codes is list of words:

```
for i in codes:
    a = '`%s`, '.join(%code for code in codes)
```

Comment: for i in codes:
    a = '`%s`, '.join(%code for code in codes)
codes is list of words

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply with `str.join()` and `str.format()` functions:

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
res = ', '.join('"{}"'.format(i) for i in a)
print(res)
```

The output:

```
"a", "b", "c"
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy as pie:

```
string = ""
for i in a:
    string = string + "\"" + i + "\", "
string = string[:-2:]
```

Just join them one-by-one as you normally would, and then strip the extra comma and space at the end.